# Visual Studio - how to reverse optimized code

Tags: debugging

I need some help.  I have put in dozens of hours into a VB.NET project, it has been built in release mode and distributed.  Now I have to make some changes to it, and I am unable to debug it properly.  My code changes result in behavior where my code is not even recognized.

Also, I installed Visual Studio 2013 recently (moving from 2010), but this project behaves the same in both environments.

I believe that my code has become 'optimized'.  The error window tells me that code is being skipped over, and that my code is optimized and JIT is checked.

I have turned off JIT, and I have tried everything to make this project work again that I could think of.  I am desperately wanting to know how I can get this project to be in a state where it will debug each line of code again when I make changes.

I can even purposely write bad code, and the debugger does not see it.

This project is now in debug mode, not release.  I have checked and followed threads on every thing that other people have done to solve this issue, but nothing works for me.

Either my project launches and works properly as it is coded, or if I change any code only the form launches with no code being run - at all.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The applications that I was struggling with were all built in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 10. I was trying to work with these in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7.

Once I tried to work with them on Windows 10 (visual Studio 2013 this time), they started working and debugging just fine.

I think it may have been DLL assembly paths? Took me more than a week, but I figured out my issue by moving from Win7x64 to Win10x64.